# Query gives error as products.product_slug is not in group by

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am creating simple query in laravel which gives error i want sum of sub_total column with product_slug parameter from table

```
 $items=DB::table('carts')
                 ->join('products','products.product_id','=','carts.product_id')
                 ->select('carts.user_id',\DB::raw('sum(sub_total) as total'),'products.product_slug')
                 ->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])
                 ->groupBy('user_id')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: you cannot select `products.product_slug` while ` ->groupBy('user_id')` because  `products.product_slug` is uniqee not `user_id`

Comment: Can you show the sql error you got ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul in single query i want to select sum and product_slug .. what is solution?

Comment: what is error ?